# .NET: How to copy files using Windows "Copy Files" dialog

Tags: .net, windows, filesystems, copy

.NET: How can I copy the files using Windows "Copy Files" dialog. I need to bulk copy multiple files. Does there exists any .NET 2.0 library/method that allows me to do it in crossplatform manner without invoking Windows platform specific libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the "Windows 'Copy Files' Dialog" you will be required to invoke "Windows platform specific libraries."

Answer (score 14):

SHFileOperation, it is well supported by the standard .NET framework.  Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and use the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory.aspx) method.  Several overloads are available that allows you to control what the UI looks like and how to handle errors.

Comment: Probably one of the best-kept secrets of VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Google for IProgressDialog - this is an Interface that gives you the functionality that you request

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find the needed functionality at the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

If everything else fails, it may work the ugly way: create an invisible Windows Explorer window, and manipulate it to start a copying process.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can make your own dialog.

It's not necessarily a difficult task though:

- If you have VS2005 then unpack the `VS2005ImageLibrary.zip` located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\VS2005ImageLibrary` on a 64 bit system or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\VS2005ImageLibrary` on a 32 bit system.
- Once you have unpacked the zip file, there will several animated GIF's of the file copy dialog's animation.  These also come in .AVI format.
- Choose one of the animated GIFs.
- Create a dialog with a picture box on it.  Assign the GIF to the picture box's `image` property.
- Add a label below the animation to specify what file is being copied.
- Drive the file-copy operation using threads updating the dialog as necessary.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that it's not really "Windows's Copy Files' Dialog", it's Explorer's dialog. So, it's have to find a way to programmatically control Explorer. (May be possible via COM or WMI)