# Using a windows file copying or file moving animation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show a Copying-files dialog/form while manually copying files in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041211/show-a-copying-files-dialog-form-while-manually-copying-files-in-c)

In C# windows forms programming, is there a way to include in my own application the animation windows always uses when copying files. As shown in picture below:

[image: File copying animation]

Comment: this one is not the standard Windows one, is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a Copying-files dialog/form while manually copying files in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041211/show-a-copying-files-dialog-form-while-manually-copying-files-in-c) The accepted answer is exactly what you need. Also see: [.NET: How to copy files using Windows “Copy Files” dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561570/net-how-to-copy-files-using-windows-copy-files-dialog)

Comment: I also can't help but notice that the custom file dialog you're using to replace the standard one provided by Explorer provides the ability to *slow down* the file copy speed. Do you find yourself using that often?

Comment: Sorry - this is the result of some hasty googling - i don't need the speed options... Link to other question looks ideal - cheers

Comment: Don't feel bad about not finding those other questions. You have to know what you're looking for. As some of the comments there indicate, this is a pretty well-hidden feature of the .NET Framework! (And I was mostly kidding about the speed options. Though I've never seen that shell replacement before.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/avi_animation.aspx) after some searching in google. The good thing about this article is that it includes the animation directly from the Shell, so that you don't have to program it yourself **and** that the graphics will be updated according to the windows version it runs.

Comment: Yeah, except don't do this. There's no guarantee that the resource ID of the animation won't change in future versions of Windows. This is completely undocumented for a reason. Beyond that, the code is in C; it'll take some work to convert it to C#. And completely unnecessary work: the shell already lets you use its file copy dialog for free with `SHFileOperation`. There's no reason to create your own.